# Is it possible to rewrite SAMPLE BY query as GROUP BY in QuestDB?

Tags: sql, database, questdb

I have the following SAMPLE BY query:

```
SELECT ts, min(temp), max(temp), avg(temp)
FROM temperature
SAMPLE BY 10s;
```

I'd like to rewrite it as a GROUP BY, so that QuestDB runs it multi-threaded. How can I do that? I've noticed `date_trunc(unit, timestamp)` in the docs, but the function doesn't accept arguments like 10s.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the query in the following way:

```
SELECT (ts - ts%10000000)::timestamp as ts, min(temp), max(temp), avg(temp)
FROM temperature
ORDER BY ts;
```

Here, we truncate the timestamp to 10 seconds (`ts - ts%10000000` - native QuestDB's time resolution is in microseconds) and cast it from LONG back to TIMESTAMP column type. Notice that the `GROUP BY` clause is optional in QuestDB, so we omit it. The rest is as simple as ordering the result set time-wise with `ORDER BY ts`.